# How to show Error or Validation messages only after form is submitted and not when user is typing in antd?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have created a form using Ant Design with Reactjs. It works great except it shows error messages that I have specified for each field under the input field before the "Submit" button is even clicked and user is typing in. It looks very odd and I would like to change that behavior. I want to show these messages only after the submit button is clicked. Is there a way to do it?

I went through the official doc. I couldn't find anything regarding "async validator" or "getFieldDecorator" that suggested what I wanted to achieve.

The "getFieldDecorator" to specify validation rules and error messages for each field is set in this way:

```
<Form.Item label="Title" style={{ margin: 0 }}>
  {getFieldDecorator('Title', {
    rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input the title', whitespace: true }], initialValue: title
  })(<Input onChange={this.onTitleChange.bind(this)} value={title} />)}
</Form.Item>
```

My "OnSubmit()" method looks like this:

```
handleSubmit = () => {
  this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
    if (err) {
      return;
    }
    this.handleSaveBanner();
  });
};
```

Expected is to show error messages only after the submit button is clicked and not before that even if user types invalid inputs or leaves it blank. Help would be appreciated since I am new to React.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please look through this. https://ant.design/components/form/#getFieldDecorator(id,-options)-parameters.
There is a option named `validateTrigger`. It can control when to do validation.
Wish it may hlp you.

Comment: when I am using it, a strange warning message is thrown on the console saying something like "React doesn't recognize the "validateTrigger" prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase fobo instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element."

Comment: Maybe your usage is wrong.
`<Form.Item label="Title" style={{ margin: 0 }}>
  {getFieldDecorator("Title", {
    rules: [
      { required: true, message: "Please input the title", whitespace: true }
    ],
    initialValue: title,
    validateTrigger: 'onSubmit'
  })(<Input onChange={this.onTitleChange.bind(this)} value={title} />)}
</Form.Item>`
Set it in options of `getFieldDecorator` as string. Try this.

Comment: <FormItem label="Title" style={{ margin: 0 }}>
              {getFieldDecorator('Title', {
                validateTrigger: "handleCreate",
                rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input the title of banner!', whitespace: true }], initialValue: title
              })(<Input onChange={this.onTitleChange.bind(this)} />)}
            </FormItem>

Comment: the above is how am I doing it...still the warning pertains

Comment: The `validateTrigger` must be React input element attribute. Just like `onChange` or `onClick`. You set the function created by yourself.

Comment: Oh yeah. My bad! I got it now. I was passing a custom function instead of defaults. Specifying the default onSubmit resolved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned above we just have to specify the trigger, `validateTrigger`. In our case `onSubmit` should do the job.

```
{
   initialValue: '', 
   rules: [{message: 'Cannot leave blank', required: true},
      {max: 25, message: 'Must be less than 25', min: 20},
   ],
   validateTrigger: 'onSubmit' // or 'onBlur' , default -> 'onChange' (change as you wish)
}
```